# SystemVerilog macros not needing a ';' at the end of a line

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

In *SystemVerilog*, it is not required to add a '`;`' at the end of a line.  For example:

```
`uvm_do(pkt)
```

I wonder why the compiler can handle this, but can't handle regular lines without the '`;`'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SystemVerilog always requires semicolons at the end of a **statement**.

However, you need to look at the code expanded by the UVM macros.  Most macros expand into code that looks like:

```
`define uvm_whatever \
    begin \
       some_code(); \
    end
```

If you were to type out the begin/end code manually, you would not need a semicolon after the `end`.  Therefore, you do not need a semicolon at the end of the macro call.

Here is a quote from the UVM docs:

> Macros represent text substitutions, not statements, so they should
>   not be terminated with semi-colons.